# Get Meta Value Without Duplicating

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to get Meta Value from Woocommerce Order Item Meta without duplicate?

```
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id);
    $order_items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $order_items as $order_item_id => $item  ) {        
            $item_data = $item->get_data();
            $custom_field = wc_get_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, '_nbd', true );
            echo $custom_field.'<br />';
            }
```

The results of $custom_field

```
21efe931617815386
26fdf541617815440
21efe931617815386
26fdf541617815440
```

expected result:

```
21efe931617815386
26fdf541617815440
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push every `$custom_field` to array and check it's already in array with `in_array` to preventing duplicate. check the below code.

```
$custom_fields = array();
$order         = wc_get_order( $order_id);
$order_items   = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $order_items as $order_item_id => $item  ) { 
   
    $item_data    = $item->get_data();    
    $custom_field = wc_get_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, '_nbd', true );

    if( !in_array( $custom_field, $custom_fields ) ){
        $custom_fields[] = $custom_field;
        echo $custom_field.'<br />';
    }

}
$custom_fields = array_unique( $custom_fields );
```

Comment: sorry, but i still get same result :(